# Setting the frame.size using the dot operator

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIController and as you all know `UIController` is associated to a view and you can access it using the getter and setters methods which are synthesized

```
UIController controller = init code ..
```

..
`controller.view` -> this gives me my `UIView` object which retained and autoreleased, this will be synthesized get method(If at all my synthesized getmethod understanding is correct)

```
controller.view.frame -> this gives me my CGRect struct

controller.view.frame.size -> CGSize struct
```

why cannot I assign a value directly to this frame structure

```
controller.view.frame.size.width = 20;
```

for the above statement I get this error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

This is a normal c dot  operator I think it should work.Please enlighten if I am missing anything

Comment: This question is the #1 reason why I think dot syntax should never have been introduced in Objective-C.  It causes confusion and was totally unnecessary.

Comment: "This is a normal c dot operator" > No, it's not.  The first two things that are receiving the operator are objects, and objects do not exist in C.  Therefore, this *cannot* be a "normal" C dot operator. (Technically, the first two things struct references, which means you'd want to use the arrow `->` operator, but then you're delving into directly and externally accessing instance variables, **WHICH IS VERY BAD**)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the dot operator in this situation is using the `frame` getter method behind the scenes. Since the frame property is a `CGRect`, which is a simple C struct, `frame` returns you a copy of the value, not a pointer to the value.  Changing it will modify the CGRect you have copied locally on the stack, not the CGRect of your view's frame property.  To update the actual frame property you must go through the setter method `[yourView setFrame:yourNewFrame];` or `yourView.frame = yourNewFrame;`.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest to solve that is to set the whole frame again

```
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(controller.view.frame.origin.x, controller.view.frame.origin.y, 20, controller.view.frame.size.height);
```

the reason why this is not working directly is described in James link, it has only getters.

Answer (score -1):

Dot syntax is just syntax sugar.

In this case, this code:

```
controller.view.frame.size.width = 20;
```

Is actually this code:

```
[[controller view] frame].size.width = 20;
```

In C terms, that's like this:

```
ViewGetFrame(ControllerGetView(controller)).size.width = 20;
```

Bottom line is you can't set a subfield of a function result this way. And even if you could, it wouldn't affect the original but only a copy.